# Бинарный поиск списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал код для поиска бинарным способом, он работает, но не могу понять, в чём проблема...

> Задание:
>
> Программа получает отсортированный по возрастанию список чисел (на
> первой строке через запятую с пробелом) и число N (на второй строке).
> Требуется определить, есть ли число N в списке. Если есть, вывести
> индекс элемента. Если числа нет, вывести No. В программе реализовать
> алгоритм двоичного поиска.
>
> Входные данные
>
> ```
> -100 -83 -76 -72 -59 -24 31 66 77 94 77
> ```
>
> Выходные данные 8
>
> Входные данные
>
> ```
> -63 -48 -44 -35 -31 -30 9 25 43 59 60 77 85  
> -92
> ```
>
> Выходные данные No

Проблема следующая, этот код должен работать в встроенном интерпретаторе на сайте, первое число должно быть input(список для поиска) и искомое число.

```
from random import randint


a = []
a = input()

value = input()

mid = len(a) // 2 
low = 0
high = len(a) - 1


while a[mid] != value and low <= high:
    if value > a[mid]:
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        high = mid - 1
    mid = (low + high) // 2


if low > high:
    print("No")
else:
    count = a.count(value)
    if count > 1:
        print(f'{mid}-{mid + count}')
    else:
        print(mid)
```

Что вводит программа в input для списка:

```
-95, -93, -81, -76, -52, -50, -37, -16, -16, -15, 5, 21, 40, 45, 49, 52, 54, 70, 78
```

Искомое число:

```
-76
```

Но код почему-то не работает, и вылезает ответ 'NO', то есть искомое число не было найдено, хотя если запустить этот же процесс на компе, всё заработает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через input() разве не строка приходит, которую ещё надо парсить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, что получаемые через `input()` строки надо ещё распарсить и превратить первую строку в список чисел, а вторую в одиночное число. Примерно так:

```
a = list(map(int, map(str.strip, input().split(','))))
value = int(input())
```